# How to unit test Clob conversion to String?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

This simple method returns all the content of a `Clob` retrieved from the database as `String`.

How can I test/mock it properly, guaranteeing it will always return the full content of the `Clob` argument (assuming its size will not be higher than an Integer)?

```
import java.sql.Clob;

public class ClobUtils {

    public static String clobToString(Clob clob) throws Exception {

        if(clob.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new Exception("Clob is too big to be handled by the application.");
        }

        // Assumes that Clob content can fit in the String
        return clob.getSubString(1, Long.valueOf(clob.length()).intValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: I can tell you right now you cannot guarentee it, as your code will fail if clob.length() is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: @ControlAltDel Good eye. I will look into it.

Comment: @ControlAltDel We have a constraint in which the XML will never get close to that size, but your point is valid so I added the constraint that should fix the logic. How can I mock that Clob now?

Comment: there's a much easier way to cast a long to an int `(int)clob.length()`.

Comment: implement a Clob and pass it to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to test `getSubString` or `length`. it's already tested by guys from sun and your db provider.  what you should test is that you are using them correctly. apparently you cannot do it by mocking clob because you would test nothing or you would have to implement your own part of jdbc (and therefore you would test wrong implementation).

what you should do is to do integration tests. setup your database, fill it with known data, run ClobUtils and check if it returns expected string. and yes, setting good, automated integration tests is not straightforward nor very easy but doable with reasonable effort.

Comment: I am not trying to test the API, you are correct. It is my implementation that should be tested which uses the Clob. Do you know any framework what would help me do it? Like JOOQ or DbUnit? I have already implemented the Mock class for Clob. If it follows spec, It shouldn't matter it is not integrated, but the test looks ugly.

Comment: that's why you should not mock it. that mock gives you nothing as you don't know if it's implemented correctly and is you db vendor has any quirks with clobs. regarding tools: we quit dbunit and used and use our production ORM (hibernate) to build exactly same database on tests as it does on production. we did our own wrappers to clean up the db between tests

Comment: We can't afford a real database in terms of project structure right now. I have configured H2 in-memory and it works fine on Oracle mode. That should do the trick for now.